# How to wrap some items with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I have this code which I can't directly modify:

```
<div id="registerMessage"> 
   <div class="pageTitle" style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;">
      Register 
   </div> 
   Some bla bla bla
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="ardir" value="" /> 
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="insert" /> 
<label>Email </label>
<div>
   <input  name="user[email]" id="user[email]" type="text" value=""  size="35" class="inputReg" />
</div>

<label>Password (5 chars)</label>
<div>
   <input name="user[passwd]" type="password" value=""  size="35" class="inputReg" />
</div>

<label>Password (confirm)</label>
<div>
   <input name="user[password_confirm]" type="password" value=""  size="35" class="inputReg" />
</div>

<div id="memomessage">
    (Other bla bla bal)
</div>
```

I need to wrap from the first label to the last `div` (memomessage excluded) into a new `div`:

```
<div id="registerBox"> the code of before </div>
```

Comment: What is the first parent of all of these elements? Is there a DIV that contains all of this?

Comment: Yes.. sorry, the code I posted is contained into a div named <div class="reg-left">

Comment: @Felix Kling I'm a really beginner of jquery I'm reading a book just now to learn it... I tried with insertAdd and insertBefore functions, but as far as I've understood I can't use them to wrap something, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('label:first').nextAll().andSelf().not('#memomessage').wrapAll('<div id="registerBox">')
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2JMq/2/)

Answer (score 2):

use following

```
$('label:first').prev().nextUntil('#memomessage').wrapAll('<div id="registerBox"></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eeusN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care specifically about `#memomessage` and want to get label and div pairs, you can use the [next-adjacent](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) selector:

```
var newDiv = $('<div />', {id:'registerBox'});
$('label + div').prev().andSelf().wrapAll(newDiv);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/x6pSZ/